# How to post object (include byte array) in retrofit?

Tags: android, arrays, post, retrofit

I convert captured image to byte array and trying to post object(include byte array) to server in `Retrofit` but it didn't work. Here's my code, thank you.

Photo_List.java

```
public class Photo_List {

int FileId;
byte[] Picture;
String User;

public Photo_List(int FileId, byte[] Picture, String User) {
    this.FileId=FileId;
    this.User=User;
    this.Picture=Picture;
}
public int getFileId() {
    return FileId;
}
public byte[] getPicture() {
    return Picture;
}

public String getUser() {
    return User;
}
```

}

--My Method--

```
 private void multipartImageUpload() {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, bos);
    byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("MYURL")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    Photo_List item = new Photo_List(5, bitmapdata, "michonne");

    ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

    Call<Photo_List> photo_listCall = apiService.postImage(item);

    photo_listCall.enqueue(new Callback<Photo_List>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Photo_List> call, Response<Photo_List> response) {
            Log.d("GG", response.message());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " :) ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Photo_List> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("WP", t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ":(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });}
```

ApiService.java

```
public interface ApiService {

@POST("api/r_photo")
Call<Photo_List> postImage(@Body Photo_List items);
```

}

---

**POST api/**

public HttpResponseMessage Post(Photo Photo)

Comment: try it https://appsgit.com/step-by-step-guide-how-to-upload-image-using-android-retrofit/

Comment: try to use @multipart notation in retrofit. Try this link https://github.com/sushildlh/Modules/wiki/Upload-File-Using-Retrofit